# Нужно ли кавычить "темные круги" под глазами?

Tags: кавычки

> "Темные круги" под глазами?

Нужны ли кавычки?

Answer (score 4):

Кавычки не нужны, если только словосочетание "темные круги" не используется в каком-нибудь необычном значении. К примеру, кто-то нарисовал себе черным фломастером круги под глазами. В этом случае использование кавычек придаст ироническое значение.